# Comply with domain verification requirements

Tags: google-oauth

We are working on the Oauth Consent screen and it is stuck at  below screen even after the completing the domain verification process even after a week.
please let us know how to move it forward.

Verification Status
Pending developer action
Complete all actions below. Update your email thread with our Trust and Safety team after you have completed an action. The Trust and Safety team will continue the verification process once all actions are completed. Learn more

Action Required
Comply with domain verification requirements
Ensure your application's domains have completed the Search Console verification process

Comment: Did you ever get past this? I am stuck as well with no email from the Trust and Safety team.

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case, I received an email from the Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team. 

I too was expecting for this to be an automated process where having the domain verified would continue the application, but in actual fact you need to reply to the email as well.

Comment: please accept the answer, as this is way to go.

Comment: @RyanTaylor did you ever get the email?

Answer (score 3):

after submitting the app, I got email with such content:

```
 [Action Needed] Verify Domain(s)

Hi,
Thanks for your patience while we reviewed your project.

To continue with the verification process, you need to update your project PROJECTNAME (id: projectid) to comply with our requirements.

Domain Verification

Please verify the ownership of the following domain(s):

fqdn.com, fqdn.eu
Go to the Search Console to complete the domain verification process. The account you use must be either a Project Owner or a Project Editor on PROJECTNAME (id: projectid).

If the listed domain(s) are not required for the project, please remove them from the authorized domains section of your OAuth Consent Screen in Google Cloud Console. 

Please note: The project you are seeing is your own.

When you've made these updates to your project, please reply to this email to confirm that you're now in compliance.

If you have any other questions, you can read the OAuth Application Verification FAQ or reply directly to this email.

GO TO MY CONSOLE
Thanks,
The Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team
```

The key sentence is

**When you've made these updates to your project, please reply to this email to confirm that you're now in compliance.**

Yes, reply to email for manual reapplication!!!

Comment: Confirmed that I never even got an email

Comment: @TheMuffinMan did you ever get an email? or how did you proceed?

Comment: I finally got an email and have been able to proceed. When replying to it I get the next email in a day or two.

Comment: I have not gotten an email after 12 hours from submitting. Although it was Sunday evening when I submitted. How long does it take to hear back?

Comment: Same here. I have been waiting for 2 weeks already, no email yet. Is there any way to trigger the email? Arunas Bartisius, could you give the email address of the Trust & Safety Team?

Comment: The reply email address is unique for your request, so they can identify response. Please search your inbox for content like "[Action Needed] Verify Domain(s)" and iclude spam and trash. Then reply to this email.

Comment: still no such email here :-(