# Reviving email thread with Google Apps trust and Safety team

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps

As a dev I have inherited a Google app that is not verified.

The app was left mid-way through the verification process, and the email thread mentioned on the OAuth consent screen section has long since been deleted (I have access to said admin email address, and it isn't there):

[image: OAuth consent screen - google console]

I have looked through google help resources and stack overflow questions such as this:

[Comply with domain verification requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899331/comply-with-domain-verification-requirements)

But I can't seem to find a way to restart or resurrect this email conversation with Google having deleted the original thread. I don't really want to have to delete the existing app and create a new one as there are customers using it (as an unverified app).

Is there a way for me to have the verification emails resent, does anyone know?

For some additional context - I want to reopen the verification conversation to allow only enterprise accounts to use the app, as described here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#enterprise&zippy=%2Cmy-application-has-users-with-enterprise-accounts-from-another-google-workspace-domain-how-does-this-apply-to-my-google-workspace-or-cloud-identity-enterprise-accounts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad - you just have to go in and edit the app, make any change, and you are prompted that a new email will be sent.